# How to find an Object by a parameter with help of Promise in a JSON Array?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

My JSON request returns the following:

```
{"page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "poster_path": "/9O7gLzmreU0nGkIB6K3BsJbzvNv.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Framed in the 1940s for the double murder of his wife and her lover, upstanding banker Andy Dufresne begins a new life at the Shawshank prison, where he puts his accounting skills to work for an amoral warden. During his long stretch in prison, Dufresne comes to be admired by the other inmates -- including an older prisoner named Red -- for his integrity and unquenchable sense of hope.",
      "release_date": "1994-09-10",
      "genre_ids": [
        18,
        80
      ],
      "id": 278,
      "original_title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
      "original_language": "en",
      "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
      "backdrop_path": "/xBKGJQsAIeweesB79KC89FpBrVr.jpg",
      "popularity": 5.446135,
      "vote_count": 5250,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 8.32
    },
    {
      "poster_path": "/lIv1QinFqz4dlp5U4lQ6HaiskOZ.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Under the direction of a ruthless instructor, a talented young drummer begins to pursue perfection at any cost, even his humanity.",
      "release_date": "2014-10-10",
      "genre_ids": [
        18,
        10402
      ],
      "id": 244786,
      "original_title": "Whiplash",
      "original_language": "en",
      "title": "Whiplash",
      "backdrop_path": "/6bbZ6XyvgfjhQwbplnUh1LSj1ky.jpg",
      "popularity": 9.001948,
      "vote_count": 2072,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 8.28
    },
```

I try to find an specific object after its Id, with the help of a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

    constructor(private http:Http) { }

    getMovies(): Promise<Movie[]>{

        return this.http.get('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=API-KEY')
            .toPromise()
            .then((res:Response) => res.json()['results'])

    }
    getMovie(id: number): Promise<Movie> {
        return this.getMovies()
            .then(movies => movies.find(movie => movie.id == id));

    }
}
```

The above getMovie() method returns a EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise), id undefined error.
How can I find the requested object?

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, what does it print if you do: `movies => { console.log("looking for id: " + id); movies.find(movie => movie.id == id) }`?

Comment: @NitzanTomer It is console logging the chosen id. Hmm.. interesting. I will update my question.

Comment: Ok, so the `id` is there and should not be `undefined`. Is this the exact code you are running or did you post a modified version of it? Are you sure that the error is from that line?

Comment: @ NitzanTomer Thanks for your help it helped to solve the problem. I found the mistake. I detailed it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake in my TopmoviesDetail component. I called the getMovie(id) function, the following way:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this.movieService.getMovie(id)
                .then(movie => this.movie = movie);

        });
    }
```

In the template, I forgot to add *ngIf="movie". After I added, everything worked as expected.

```
@Component({

    selector: 'topmovies',
    template: ` 
    <div *ngIf="movie">// I forgot to add this line
    <h2>{{movie.id}}</h2>
    <h2>{{movie.original_title}} </h2>
    </div>

    `
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a plunk solving your issue.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/obarEawM6fEoPPvDTQnu?p=preview)

Please note that it is highly recommended to use Observables instead of Promises.

this are the two methods in your service.

```
getMovies() : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('./src/data.json')
}
getMovieById(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.getMovies().map( res =>{

      let response = res.json()['results'];

      return response.find(item => item.id === id)
    })
}
```

and here's the compontent

```
export class App {
  constructor(private movieService:MovieService) {
    this.movieService.getMovieById(278).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
  }
}
```

I won't go into detail on Observables here (lots of online sources). In case you aren't familiar with them, it helps a lot to think of them as a mix of promises and eventemitters.

Each time something happens, the observable emits an event to everything which subscribed to it. The subscribe can be simply seen as a forEach.

so

```
this.movieService.getMovieById(278).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

could be interpreted as

```
this.movieService.getMovieById(278).forEach(res => console.log(res))
```

and everytime the Observable emits something, the emitted value will be passed to the forEach function.

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: I found the mistake in my code, you can see the details above. I will also change my Promises to the Observable. Thanks for your input, I appreciate it.

Comment: your welcome :) please check if off if everything is resolved. Cheers